Rest API to list contents of a directory
There are a series of documents that get uploaded to a SharePoint instance. These documents need to be uploaded elsewhere and quite a few places. Currently this is a manual action that is error prone and consumes a significant amount of time. I would like to using a language like python automate the copying of this file.
For security reason I can't reveal the real names, but I'll mock the situation.
We have a SharePoint instance running at https://foo.sharepoint.com.
From this instance I navigate to what I assume is a site called 'Documentation' (http://foo.sharepoint.com/sites/Documentation) which has a landing page that links to various documents.
From here I can navigate to http://foo.sharepoint.com/sites/Documentation/MachineDocs/Shared Documents. I click on a folder called 'Customer' and in this folder is finally a list of PDF files that I need to retrieve and copy further.
I am able to call https://foo.sharepoint.com/_api/web/folders except I don't recognize any of the folders that come back in the XML response. I have already tried to use GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl using examples from the documentation for 'Shared Documents' as well as attempted to fill in the folder path relative to the site. I've tried looking at sites and attempted to use GUID functions, though I can't find what the GUID would be in share point itself for the related files.
Is there anybody that can plainly explain how exactly I am supposed to access this path?
